# local jar -package does not exist when compiling

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on a java project in intellij.It's using gradle but some of the jars I imported from a local folder.For these local jars, they are imported successfully and there is no error in the code.But when i try to compile the class, it shows 'package xxx does not exist'.
May I know how can i fix it?It works in eclipse but I want to fix it in Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this?
file-> ProjectStructre->Libraies
then click the "+" to add the local file

here is the Picture tutorial
[the first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dggly.png)
[the second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPwys.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi.That's how I import the libs.Error fixed in the java file but got package does not exist when compiling.